# OFBiz <eca> not clearing parameters between triggers

Tags: java, ofbiz

I have an entity condition action `<eca>` defined like this:

```xml
    <eca service="importAccount" event="invoke" run-on-error="true" run-on-failure="true" >
        <set field-name="serviceName" value="importAccount" />
        <set field-name="parameters.acctNum" env-name="${acctNum}" />
        <action service="serviceLogging" mode="sync"/>
    </eca>
```

When I run `importAccount` from OFBiz's webtools with an `acctNum` parameter, the `serviceLogging` service gets triggered and sees the parameter just fine.

If I then run importAccount again without an `acctNum` parameter, the `serviceLogging` service gets triggered however it gets the parameter from the previous run. I would expect it to get null since I didn't enter a parameter for the second run. The `serviceLogging` service gets the parameter from the first run on every subsequent run that I do without a parameter

Inside `serviceLogging` I have tried doing:

context.remove("parameters") at the end of the service

context.put("parameters", null) at the end of the service

but I keep getting that initial parameter on every run. How can I stop this from happening?

Thank you

**EDIT**

I believe I have found an answer. Setting a default-value prevents the SECA from getting the previous runs input parameter. However I cannot figure out how to set the default-value to null. Here is the service def:

```xml
    <service name="importAccounts" engine="java"
         location="com.hotwaxmedia.dsi.migration.MigrationServices" invoke="importAccounts" auth="true" transaction-timeout="14400">
        <description>Import Accounts from Legacy</description>
        <attribute name="glNumb" mode="IN" type="String" optional="true" default-value=" "/>
    </service>
```

However, when no input parameter is set this will pass in a space to the service, but I am looking for it to pass in a null. I have tried:

```xml
default-value="" <-- This will continue passing the previous run's parameter..

default-value="null" <-- This will pass in the string "null"

default-value="${groovy: return null}" <-- This will pass in the string "${groovy: return null}"
```

Have also tried:

```xml
    <attribute name="glNumb" mode="IN" type="String" optional="true"> 
      <default-value>
        <null xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
      </default-value>
    </attribute>
```

But this just uses the previous run's input parameter as well.

Do you know how to set a default-value of null?

Comment: Hi Minato, what is the source of importAccount service? It does not exist in OFBiz trunk.

Comment: @JacquesLeRoux I can't paste even the service definition here, but it takes in an optional String parameter and outputs 3 BigDecimal parameters and a List parameter. It's the SECA that gets triggered before this service that is getting the previous run's paramter passed in, when it should get null instead since the parameter isn't set on subsequent runs

Comment: Hi Minato, from the top of my head I don't know how to set a default-value of null in an ECA. That exists in services (simple-method, now deprecated) but I see no equivalent in ECA. This said you should better subscribe and ask on user ML https://ofbiz.apache.org/mailing-lists.html. Here you ask to one person, there to hundreds...